# Rails, OpenSSL error: certificate verify failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paypal, openssl, paypal-sandbox

I'm jumping in to make some changes in a rails app that uses activemerchant and paypal for payments. There are no problems in production with the connection but I can't get it to connect paypals sandbox from my local machine.

I'm getting `SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed` error in the browser when trying to checkout through paypal.

There are loads of articles and questions about similar problems but nothing i've seen seems to fix it... I've tried updating cert.pem in openssl. Also tried different versions of ruby, openssl etc

Tested with [doctor.rb](https://github.com/mislav/ssl-tools/blob/master/doctor.rb):

`ruby doctor.rb www.sandbox.paypal.com` works 
(edited)

**OS**: Osx Yosemite

**Ruby**: 2.1.6

**Rails**: 3.2.11

**OpenSSL**: 1.0.2d

Answer (score 0):

> ... :SSLError: hostname "sandbox.paypal.com" does not match the server certificate

The certificate you get is for `www.sandbox.paypal.com` only and thus does not match `sandbox.paypal.com`. Please use the correct hostname.

Comment: Thanks! Received the correct message in the terminal now. The original problem, that I can't contact paypal from my rails app, is still there though..

Comment: @more_is_more: Please ask a new question will the new problem description since the original problem (certificate validation) is solved. It is not possible to guess from your information what the problem is now.

Comment: The root problem is stated above, that I get `SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed` when connecting paypal from my rails app. The doctor.rb thing was jus troubleshooting and to show some information. I edited that so that there is no confusion. Sorry if it was unclear, it's my first question over here.